# Why does my camera have a delay before shooting?

Tags: nikon, shutter, nikon-d7200

I have a Nikon D7200 with a AF-S Nikkor 18-105 mm lens. For some reason, when I take a photo, it opens the shutter for a second then closes it; the photo produced is when the shutter closes. I'm confused why it takes a second to take a photo. Even when I manually focus it it has this delay. To make it weirder, it has a 2 second delay on live view. I've tried making my shutter speed as fast as possible, using sports mode, turning of RAW, but nothing works. Does anyone know why my camera takes so long to take a photo? My 12 year old Canon 1000D took photos in about 0.1-2 seconds.

Comment: What you first hear is not the shutter opening, it is the mirror raising out of the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have "Exposure Delay Mode" set? It delays the shutter to allow vibrations to settle when on a tripod.  Should be in the D4 (Shooting/Display) menu.

See [The Manual](https://download.nikonimglib.com/archive3/Q3Q8q001RCR303gJ4tp98L2fLB94/D7200UM_NT(En)04.pdf) page 280.

Comment: Thanks, guess I need to go through the manual more!